# Linking CSS/CSS3/JS to Google App Engine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-app-engine

I'm having a tough time linking my stylesheets with the .yaml file. Here is my yaml file now:

My directory looks something like this:

|-- assests -> css - js.

|-- templates -> a bunch of my html.

| main.py

| app.yaml

If I upload the css directly from a url it works fine. However, it's not working using directory mapping. Here's an example of how I upload the css:

```
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And here's the yaml file:

```
    application: app 

    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: true 

    handlers:
    - url: /assets/css/(.*\.css)
      mime_type: text/css
      static_files: /assets/css/\1
      upload: /assets/css/(.*\.css)

    - url: /assets/css/colors(.*\.css)
      mime_type: text/css
      static_files: /assets/css/colors\1
      upload: /assets/css/colors(.*\.css)

    - url: /assets/js/(.*\.js)
      mime_type: text/js
      static_files: /assets/js/\
      upload: /assets/js/(.*\.js)

    - url: .*
      script: main.app

    libraries:
    - name: webapp2
      version: "2.5.2"
    - name: jinja2 
      version: latest
```

Any ideas?

```
SOLUTION: 

application: app 
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true 

handlers:
- url: /assets/css(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: assets/css/\1
  upload: assets/css/(.*\.css)

- url: /assets/css/colors(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: assets/css/colors/\1
  upload: assets/css/colors(.*\.css)

- url: /assets/js/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/js
  static_files: assets/js/\1
  upload: assets/js/(.*\.js)

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2 
  version: latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, make your stylesheet hrefs absolute (i.e., start with `/`), since these are always relative to the base of the web serving path, and not relative to any particular page.

Second, in `app.yaml`, `static_files` (and `static_dir`) are relative to the base directory of the app, so remove the leading `/` on those paths.

Comment: I am still having trouble with it, I updated my post with what my yaml file looks like.

Comment: Oh lol. Never mind! Wasn't suppose to remove the '/' from the url.